# Need explanation for conditional probabilities satisfying axioms of probabilities

Tags: probability, statistics, independence

I am reading my textbook "A first course in probability". I am learning about how conditional probabilities also satisfy all the properties of ordinary probabilities. In one example, a conditional probability was expanded into this:

$\def\P{\mathop{\mathsf P}} \P(A_2\mid A_1) = \P(A_2\mid A \cap A_1)\P(A\mid A_1) + \P(A_2\mid A^\mathsf c \cap A_1)\P(A^\mathsf c\mid A_1)$

I separated intersecting terms with '$\cap$' to make it easier to read. $A^\mathsf c$ is just the compliment of $A$.

I understand for normal probabilities that:

$\P(A_2) = \P(A_2\mid A)\P(A) + \P(A_2\mid A^\mathsf c)\P(A^\mathsf c)$

But could somebody explain how does this work for conditional probabilities too?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to use [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type mathematics here.

Comment: What happened when you replaced each $P(B\mid C)$ by $P(B\cap C)/P(C)$?

Answer (score 2):

$\def\P{\mathop{\mathsf P}}\def\c{{\mathsf c}}$

Recall that by the definition of conditional probability the Law of Total Probability is:

$\P(A_2) ~{=\P(A_2\cap A)+\P(A_2\cap A^\c)\\=\P(A_2\mid A)\P(A)+\P(A_2\mid A^\c)\P(A^\c)}$

And similarly for a conditional probability:

$\P(A_2\mid A_1) ~{=\dfrac{\P(A_1\cap A_2)}{\P(A_1)} \\ = \dfrac{\P(A_1\cap A_2\cap A)+\P(A_1\cap A_2\cap A^\c) }{\P(A_1)}\\ = \dfrac{\P(A_2\mid A_1\cap A)\P(A_1\cap A)+\P(A_2\mid A_1\cap A^\c)\P(A_1\cap A^\c) }{\P(A_1)}\\ =\P(A_2\mid A \cap A_1)\P(A\mid A_1) + \P(A_2\mid A^\c \cap A_1)\P(A^\c\mid A_1)}$

That is all.